# Some Kindle books on my pc do not appear on my Android

Tags: library, sync

I started with Kindle for PC - recently I have added an Android tablet.
Most books have synced OK between the two devices.
But 3 books on my PC - Pride and Prejudice, Aesop's Fables, and Treasure Island - appear ONLY on the PC.  I have tries syncing, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to copy the books over using a USB cable?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've solved my own question!

It seems that all three books were free downloads.
So I've downloaded them again to my tablet, at zero cost.

I still think they should have appeared in the library automatically  ......

Comment: Yeah, I had this problem with "Aseop's Fables".  Thank you for the including the solution.